# Separate odd and even indexes in a sequence array

Tags: arrays, swift

A for in loop won't work because type int is does not conform to protocol Sequence.

I have 3 arrays:

1 master array, where the array is stored

1 odd array, empty at the beginning

1 even array, empty at the beginning

The meaning is that all the odd indexes of the master array will be stored at the odd array, and the same for the even array.

```
    while i < masterA.count {
        evenA.append(masterA[i])
        if i > 0{
        oddA.append(masterA[i - 1])
        }
        i += 2
    }
```

However this does not work good enough. Anyone has a better idea?

Comment: Do you mean that _elements_ of `masterA` that have odd indices should be stored in `oddA`, and conversly, elements of `masterA` that have even indices should be stored in `evenA`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is another possible solution:

```
let evenA = stride(from: 0, to: masterA.count, by: 2).map { masterA[$0] }
let oddA = stride(from: 1, to: masterA.count, by: 2).map { masterA[$0] }
```

The elements are "picked" directly from the even/odd positions in the source array.

**Performance comparison:**

My simple, not very sophisticated ad-hoc benchmarking code:

```
import Swift

let N = 10_000_000
let RUNS = 50

let masterA = (0..<N).map { $0 }

var times = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
for _ in 1...RUNS {

    // filter+map (dfri)
    do {
        let start = Date()
        let evenA = masterA.enumerated().filter { $0.0 % 2 == 0 }.map{ $0.1 }
        let oddA = masterA.enumerated().filter { $0.0 % 2 != 0 }.map{ $0.1 }
        let time = Date().timeIntervalSince(start)
        times.0 += time
    }

    // flatMap (dfri)
    do {
        let start = Date()
        let evenA = masterA.enumerated().flatMap { $0 % 2 == 0 ? $1 : nil }
        let oddA = masterA.enumerated().flatMap { $0 % 2 != 0 ? $1 : nil }
        let time = Date().timeIntervalSince(start)
        times.1 += time
    }

    // stride+map (me)
    do {
        let start = Date()
        let evenA = stride(from: 0, to: masterA.count, by: 2).map { masterA[$0] }
        let oddA = stride(from: 1, to: masterA.count, by: 2).map { masterA[$0] }
        let time = Date().timeIntervalSince(start)
        times.2 += time
    }

    // loop (Keiwan)
    do {
        let start = Date()
        var evenA = [Int]()
        var oddA = [Int]()

        for (index, element) in masterA.enumerated() {
            if index % 2 == 0 {
                evenA.append(element)
            } else {
                oddA.append(element)
            }
        }
        let time = Date().timeIntervalSince(start)
        times.3 += time
    }
}

print(N, RUNS)
print(times.0/Double(RUNS), times.1/Double(RUNS), times.2/Double(RUNS), times.3/Double(RUNS))
```

Results: (On a MacBook, running in Release mode)

```
#elements   filter+map  flatMap   stride+map  loop
10,000      0.0001      0.00008   0.00004     0.00004
100,000     0.0016      0.0008    0.0004      0.0004
1,000,000   0.0295      0.0136    0.0090      0.0091
10,000,000  0.3025      0.1332    0.0909      0.1250
```

Answer (score 8):

Possibly I'm misunderstanding your intent, but it seems as if you want that *elements* of `masterA` that have odd indices should be stored in `oddA`, and conversely, elements of `masterA` that have even indices should be stored in `evenA`.

You can achieve this by filtering `masterA` w.r.t. the indices of `masterA`, readily available from `masterA.enumerated()`.

```
let masterA = [4, 5, 2, 1, 7, 8, 1]

let evenA = masterA.enumerated().filter { $0.0 % 2 == 0 }.map{ $0.1 }
let oddA = masterA.enumerated().filter { $0.0 % 2 != 0 }.map{ $0.1 }

print(evenA) // [4, 2, 7, 1]
print(oddA)  // [5, 1, 8]
```

As @Hamish points out in his comment below, we could use the `compactMap` (Swift 3: `flatMap`) as an alternative to the chained `filter` and `map`.

```
let evenA = masterA.enumerated().compactMap { $0 % 2 == 0 ? $1 : nil }
let oddA = masterA.enumerated().compactMap { $0 % 2 != 0 ? $1 : nil }
```

The latter `compactMap` solution is briefer, whereas the `filter` ... `map` solution possibly shows intent slightly clearer. In this particular brevity vs. semantics competition, I would personally prefer the `compactMap` solution.

Comment: And of course, a `filter` and `map` can always be boiled down to a `flatMap` – `let evenA = masterA.enumerated().flatMap { $0 % 2 == 0 ? $1 : nil }` :)

Comment: @Hamish I don't know why I even resort to `filter` followed by `map` these days, as I'm always reminded of the boiled down `flatMap` solution xD thanks!

Comment: It would be interesting to know which one is faster for large arrays: filter+map, flatMap, or perhaps `let evenA = stride(from: 0, to: masterA.count, by: 2).map { masterA[$0] }` ?

Comment: @MartinR I guess as long as filter is lazy, the first two should be (speculating wildly) comparable, but I have a feeling the `stride` solution will be faster (no conditionals involved). Anyone up for testing? :)

Comment: 10 runs with an array with 1,000,000 elements: filter+map: 0.3068 sec, flatMap: 0.127 sec, stride: 0.0967 sec, explicit loop (Keiwan's code):  0.0949 sec. – For 10,000,000 elements, stride is the fastest.

Comment: @MartinR Nice job! A bit surprised that there's not a bigger difference between `flatMap` and `stride`/traditional loop (until really huge arrays). Care to add an answer with the `stride` solution as well as the benchmarks for those interested? :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use `enumerated()` to get both the index and the value while looping:

```
for (index, element) in masterA.enumerated() {
    if index % 2 == 0 {
        evenA.append(element)
    } else {
        oddA.append(element)
    }
}
```

This will store every `element` of `masterA` with an odd index in `oddA` and every element with an even index in `evenA`.

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari: `0` is an even number, so storing the element with index `0` in `evenA` seems quite correct to me.

Comment: @MartinR Again it depends on user to user. For me any element at first position is the odd one( Means index 0)

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari Also, OP specifically asks for odd _indices_ (_"... that all the **odd indexes** of the master array will be stored at the **odd array** ..."_), which could hint that the OP has the same perspective on odd/even order as this answer.

Comment: @Keiwan makes sense. Take +1 from me too. Just make a minor edit

Answer (score 1):

Another solution

> **Swift 3.0 code**

```
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
var oddArray = [Int]()
var evenArray = [Int]()

for (index,value) in array.enumerated() {
    if index % 2 == 0 {
        // It is odd because index starts from 0 in array and I am assuming the 0 index as the odd one.
        oddArray.append(value)
    } else {
        evenArray.append(value)
    }
}
```

Odd Array = [1,3,5,7]

Even Array = [2,4,6,8]