# How to split array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array **arrays1**, how can I split this array into 2 arrays below?

```
let arrays1 = [1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 7, 6, 8, 9, 10]
```

**My expectations:**

```
let listItems1 = [1, 2, 5, 6, 9]
let listItems2 = [3, 4, 7, 8, 10]
```

Below is all my code, I am wanting to try to move number **10** from **listItems1** to **listItems2**

```
 let arrays1 = [1,3,2,4,5,7,6,8,9,10]
 let arrays2 = arrays1.chunked(into: 2)
        
 let listItems1 = arrays2.enumerated().filter { $0.offset % 2 == 0 }.flatMap { $0.element }

 let listItems2 = arrays2.enumerated().filter { $0.offset % 2 != 0 }.flatMap { $0.element }
```

```
extension Array {
    func chunked(into size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: size).map {
            Array(self[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + size, count)])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57155806/how-to-create-a-new-array-of-even-numbers-from-an-existing-array

Comment: @koen sorry,I have updated the question again

Comment: since you have a condition (even vs odd) you can use `Dictionary(grouping:)`

Answer (score 0):

```
let arrays1 = [1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 7, 6, 8, 9, 10]
let arrays2 = arrays1.chunked(into: 2)

var listItems1 = arrays2.enumerated().filter { $0.offset % 2 == 0 }.flatMap { $0.element }
var listItems2 = arrays2.enumerated().filter { $0.offset % 2 != 0 }.flatMap { $0.element }

// Check if 10 is in listItems1, and if so, remove it from listItems1 and add it to listItems2
if let index = listItems1.firstIndex(of: 10) {
    listItems1.remove(at: index)
    listItems2.append(10)
}

print(listItems1) // [1, 2, 5, 6, 9]
print(listItems2) // [3, 4, 7, 8, 10]
```

Comment: it's not the same as my question

Comment: you are trying to split, one array into 2. check your question again.
else if you provide more info, then i can help in better way

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983883/separate-odd-and-even-indexes-in-a-sequence-array